# Why does not javascript show the output when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i'm quite new to javascript and im wondering why the output wont show "Hello John, Your last name is Johnsen" when the button is clicked. I have tried several times with different code and it doesnt seem to work. I also get an error in the console where it says "Uncaught TypeError: name is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

Code and output picture: (i couldnt make it in a code box sorry)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsz1B.png)

Code:

```js
function Name() {
var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello " + firstname + <br> + "Your lat name is: " + lastname;
}
```

```html
<div>

First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" value=""><br><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname" value="">

<button onclick="Name()">Submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</div>
```

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQhwW.png)

Comment: Use the snipest  dont use image for your code , just copy past , i dont understund why you could'n past it

Comment: Also, this has absolutely **nothing** to do with Java.

Comment: I know, i removed it. Im sorry and as i said i have tried like a million times with the snipet but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Keshav When i change the function name it gives me the same error just with the new function i made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this.

```js
function clicked() {
var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello " + firstname + "<br>" + "Your lat name is: " + lastname;
}
```

```html
<div>

First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" value=""><br><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname" value="">

<button onclick="clicked()">Submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I had posted the wrong comment. I had deleted it. I got confused between  `alert` and `name`.

Comment: I'm glad that you had given me the tick mark. But there is someone who had posted the right answer before me. So, he is the real winner of the tick mark.

Answer (score 2):

`<br>` needs to be enclosed in `"`.

Comment: Omg thank you so much! i didnt know it was that simple yet so hard :P thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fname = document.getElementById('fname');
var lname = document.getElementById('lname');
var res = document.getElementById('demo')
function fullName(){
res.innerHTML = `Firstname :  ${fname.value} <br/> lastname :  ${lname.value}`;
}
```

```html
<div>

First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" value=""><br><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname" value="">

<button onclick="fullName()">Submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</div>
```